Service Fabric Local Cluster with Selenium Web Driver in Interactive Mode
I run Microsoft Service Fabric with 1 Node in Local Cluster Mode.
Is it somehow possible to start the selenium chromedriver in interactive mode from the Service?
When i start selenium chromedriver session it seems to start non-interactive or invisible in headless mode. (not sure about that)

I solved it starting chrome in debug mode and attach the chrome driver from the service to it.
Steps:
1. Start Chrome Browser manually in Debug Mode:
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=c:/tmp/selenium

2. Start Chromedriver with DebuggerAddress from ChromeOptions
// chrome options            
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();  

// set debugging address to chrome           
chromeOptions.DebuggerAddress ="127.0.0.1:9222" 

// start driver with options
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions)

you can then watch all chromedriver interactions in the chrome window from step 1.
